# Como paso de un array int con numeros introducidos por teclado a un array char

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para classe y tengo que pasar una matriz de numeros introducidas por teclado a una matriz de char , Alguien me puede ayudar,

El código es este:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] array = new int[5][5];
        char[][] array1=new char[5][5];
        char l;

        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
                System.out.print("array[" + i + "][" + j + "]: ");
                array[i][j]=input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<array.length;j++){

                System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa exactamente "pasar una matriz de números a una matriz de char"? ¿Podrías poner algún ejemplo del resultado esperado?

Comment: 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 11 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: los 1 salen en matriz y lo que quiero es pasar de esos numeros a caracteres y formar una matriz con caracteres

Comment: ¿En qué caracteres se deben de convertir esos números?

Comment: Se tiene que pasar a ASCII

Comment: Suena lógico, más, ¿Podrías detallar en que valor ASCII exactamente?

Comment: Es decir, si se convierten al valor ASCII 1 y 0 respectivamente, no se podrán ver en pantalla pues ambos son caracteres de control. Si los pasamos al ascii 49 y 48 que representan los símbolos '1' y '0', no habrá ningún cambio visible al imprimirlos por lo que no parece tener mucho sentido.

Comment: tengo que hacer que forme una palabra en diagonal que se llame Salle y con los numeros introducidos por teclado 5x5 (Matriz) 83,97,98,99,100,70,6571,73,74,78,79,76,80,81,76,82,65,66,67,68,69

Comment: Pruebo poniendo otro tipo de numero?

Comment: Pues, puedes convertir un entero a char usando paréntesis: (char) variableEntera.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si escribes System.out.println((char)65) te saldrá una letra A.

Comment: Lo harías usando (char) cada vez que guardes un valor en la matriz. Permiteme un momento, te lo quiero mostrar en una respuesta pero me tomará unos minutos escribirla.

Comment: Okay Muchas Gracias por la ayuda te lo agradezco :)

Answer (score 0):

Imaginemos que mi objetivo es mostrar la siguiente letra:

```
  __ _ 
 / _` |
} (_} }
 \__,_}
```

Pero necesito hacerlo ingresando sus valores ASCII en lugar de lso caracteres tal cual además de que debo usar una matriz. Los valores ASCII para formar esa figura serían:

```
32  32 95 95 32  95 32
32  47 32 95 96  32 124
125 32 40 95 125 32 125
32  92 95 95 44  95 125
```

Y requerirían una matriz de dimensiones 4 x 7.

Uno declararía dicha matriz con:

```
char[][] matriz = new char[4][7];
```

Y leería los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.length; fila++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < matriz[fila].length; col++) {
    System.out.print("matriz[" + fila + "][" + col + "]: ");
    matriz[fila][col] = (char)input.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Nótese que la única diferencia hasta ahora con tu código es que uso (char) para convertir un entero en un carácter.

Ahora puedo mostrar la figura anterior mediante:

```
for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.length; fila++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < matriz[fila].length; col++) {
    System.out.print(matriz[fila][col]);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Y listo, ahora solo tengo que ejecutar el programa y escribir todos los números antes mencionados para poder mostrar mi letra a.